# How can an IOS app access Google Drive files(folder,images,docs)

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

How can an IOS app access Google Drive files(folder,images,docs)

I had Integrated with Google Drives with application . The

Main Isssue is that I can See the files When i uploaded

from my ios app, when we are uploading the image from

browser , i am not able to see it in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the example [iOS application](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/objectivec), and also the [iOS quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-ios) for using the Google Drive SDK.